# Integrate or modify a flash effect 'Ken Burns Effect'

Tags: flash, flashdevelop

i´m using the moviemasher and want to upgrade it with the Ken Burns effect as .swf?  So the only informations i can give you is this link.

http://sourceforge.net/p/moviemasher/discussion/705957/thread/a52a625a/?limit=25#fa34

So i need to implement a interface? Is ther any way to download or create the Ken Burns effect to integrate it? And if it´s possible an i can download the effect free or for payment. Can i implement the interface afterwards??

best,
SnowN

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a new module. Per Doug comments in his forum, you can simply make use of the Composite Effect Module to achieve the effect. Have a look on this link:

http://sourceforge.net/p/moviemasher/discussion/705957/thread/fd8c964d/